# creating a more complex sudoku (69x6)

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I would like to know if its possible to create a "sodoku" with this rule:
in a table 69x6 i want to put in the numbers from 1 to 46 repeated 9 times,
each numbers HAS to stay in the same colum with every other number 1 and only 1 time.

Meaning: if I have the 9 colums that have the number 1 in it, the other 5x9 (45) numbers will be all the numbers from 2 to 46 so that 1 is with all numbers 1 and only 1 time.

(i made a program that tries to fill in the numbers but i was never albe to put in moer than 382of414 numbers)
here it is: http://pastebin.com/JFtb8SVg

i didnt post it here becuase its 350lines, and commented in italian, i dont so much want you to correct my program as much as tell me if what im trying to do is possible or not

Thanks

Gokalex

Comment: Interesting question ... but off-topic.  It is maths or puzzle problem, not a programming problem.

Comment: +1 for the interesting question, I think you should ask here instead though http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I am confused. In the first sentence you talk about a 69x6 table, i.e. 6 columns with 69 cells each. Then, you talk about 9 columns with 46 cells each. Which is it? Also, are there any 'horizontal' constraints?

Comment: @StephenC will do, didnt know of the existance of math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Rob will do, didnt know of the existance of math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @tobias_k the table is 69 colums 6 rows (69x6 = 414) and im filling it with the number 1-46 repeated 9 times (46x9 = 414)

Comment: If you're using numbers 1-46, 9 times each, the ideal thing would be to put them in a 46x9 grid.

Comment: @tobias_k I do not check the rows, 1 can be 9 times in the same row, i only check the colums

Comment: So the only constraint is that each number must appear in the same row as each other number exactly once? Ex. If 1 and 2 appear in the same column together, they may not appear together in any other column?

Comment: @Kevin yes, 1 and 2 have to be in the same colum 1 and only 1 time, (they cant be togheter 0 times or more than 1, they have to be toghether exacly 1 time, and that counts for every number combination)